# Is there a way to always get a table on the same page with corresponding footnotes?

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have a situation where sometimes two tables (who look nearly identical to the one in the 
MWE) are on the right page with the corresponding footnotes but then unfortunately very often not, especially in the case that I use the whole document (i.e. content of the respective chapter) in front of the tables.

For the final version I must have them on the same page. For now I'd still like to give it a shot without a `\clearpage` in front of the `table`-environment since this leaves the typical white and ugly void. Are there any best practice cases?

**edit** Decided to put the two tables in question in the appendix out of speed and convenience. Found [tablefootnote](http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) though, will try that next time.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
booktabs,
longtable,
multicol,
lipsum
}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\lipsum[1-7]

%\clearpage
\begin{table}[tcb]
\begin{center}
\caption{A special table}
%\captionof{table}{A special table}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
ABC   & B     & C     & D     & E     & A     & B     & C     & D     & E     & A     & B \\
\midrule
1     & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark \\
2     & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark \\
3     & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark & ij\footnotemark \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}
\end{table}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-32}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{Word.}    

\lipsum[8-10]


\end{document}
```

Comment: do you have to have the notes at the bottom of the _page_ (which latex doesn't really support) or under the table, which is supported by using minipage, of packages such as threeparttab;e?

Comment: Bottom of page. There are also other footnotes due to the text. They are references (via biblatex's `footcite`).

Comment: As I said latex doesn't really support that, you need to use \begin{table}[htb] to make sure it doesn't use `p`age floats, then just manually move your block of `\footnotetext` commands on to the page where the float ends up.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @David Carliste, what you are trying to achieve here is indeed quite a challenge. the main issue is in fact that you are trying to add quite a lot of footnotes at the same time, and to be fair, we can't really blame latex to think that this would be ugly.

So to go a little more into details with it, the issue is due to the way latex decides on where to put its figures. 
Each paragraphe and floating figure are eventually considered as a block of fixed size, and this is only at that point that latex does decide between which paragraph blocks to put the floating figures. This means that at that point, it does not really know any more where the footnotes have been written when they have been converted into a block.

So, when we consider that, what do we have left to "attach" the corresponding footnotes to the table without making huge changes ?

Well, I think the only solution you have is to trap the footnotes inside the same block as the table manually. 
And i think that given the number of footnotes you seem to want to add, this is not necessarily a bad idea, because you can then create several columns of these footnotes.

You could do that using something like :

```
\hbox to \headwidth{
  \hfil
  \hsize = \headwidth/2
  \vbox to 80 pt{
    \parindent=0pt
    my footnote 1

    my footnote 2
    }
  \hfil
  \hsize = \headwidth/2
  \vbox to 80 pt{
    \parindent=0pt
    my footnote 3

    my footnote 4
    }
  \hfil
  }
```

Even, by only making sure that the {table+associated footnotes} system stays at the bottom, you can pretty much make it seem like it is in fact just some fancy footnotes.

If you are really into tweaking with the footnote system, you could even try to either include the footnotes that would normally be displayed on this page within your columns or/and prevent them from going at the bottom of that one, but this might mean having to mess quite a lot with the footnote package and I wouldn't recommend that unless you really know what you are doing.